# For in ajax with MVC 4 and jQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

i have a web application build in asp.net MVC 4, and i have a problem, i'm trying to do a for cycle to full a selects. The weird thing is that when the cycle is running the alerts display the number of the maximum paramater. But the cycle calls 5 times the method in my controller.

i hope i made myself clear(I'm chilean so i don't speak  or write to good English).

Here's the jQuery and Ajax Code. The value od rowIndex is 5.

```
    for (var i = 0; i < rowIndex; i++) {
    $(function (i) {

        $.getJSON("/Admin/Administradoras/List", function (data) {
            var items = "<option>Elija Una Opcion</option>";
            alert(i);
            $.each(data, function (i, administradoras) {

                items += "<option value='" + administradoras.Value + "'>" + administradoras.Text + "</option>";
            });

            $("#Administradoras" + i).html(items);
        });


        $("#Administradoras" + i).change(function () {
            $.getJSON("/Admin/Fondos/List/" + $("#Administradoras" + i + " option:selected").attr("value"), function (data) {
                var items = "<option>Elija Una Opcion</option>";
                $.each(data, function (i, fondos) {
                    items += "<option value='" + fondos.Value + "'>" + fondos.Text + "</option>";
                });
                $("#Fondos" + i).html(items);
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Hello, i'm chilean too...PS: Cuál es tu duda??

Comment: Estoy llenando unos select con esa función (son 5 en total), cada uno se llama Administradoras1, 2, etc. Mi duda es por que i al momento de hacer alerts con el valor en cada pasada del ciclo, toma el valor de 5 y no de 1, 2, etc. Necesito hacer eso para poder poblar los select. Espero que me hayas entendido, gracias por responder!!

Comment: La respuesta de @Tim debiese servir para tu caso en específico...si tienes dudas me avisas...saludos :)

Comment: No puedo rescatar el numero del elemento seleccionado en Administradoras para poder sacar los Fondos, algo pasa que no hace nada. Gracias por tu disposición!

Comment: Y si añades una clase a tus select como sugirió @Tim??

Comment: Lo hice, el tema es que no toma el valor para poder llenar el select de Fondos. Funciona todo correctamente, pero no puedo tomar el name o id del Administrador seleccionado. Supongamos: 

<select class="Administradoras" id="Administradoras1"></select>
<select id="Fondos1"></select>

Necesito saber de que select viene (1,2,3,4 0 5) para poder saber que select de fondo actualizar. Sé muy poco de jQuery y Ajax, por eso tantas dudas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is doing exactly what it is supposed to do based on your code. You have the controller call *inside* you for loop, so it gets called 5 times. I think you want something like this:

**HTML**

```
<select class="Administradoras" id="Administradoras1"></select>
<select class="Administradoras" id="Administradoras2"></select>
<select class="Administradoras" id="Administradoras3"></select>
<select class="Administradoras" id="Administradoras4"></select>
<select class="Administradoras" id="Administradoras5"></select>
```

**JS**

```
$(function (i) {

    $.getJSON("/Admin/Administradoras/List", function (data) {
        var items = "<option>Elija Una Opcion</option>";
        alert(i);
        $.each(data, function (i, administradoras) {
            items += "<option value='" + administradoras.Value + "'>" + administradoras.Text + "</option>";
        });        
        for (var i = 0; i < rowIndex; i++) {
            $("#Administradoras" + i).html(items);
        }
    });


    $(".Administradoras").change(function () {
        $.getJSON("/Admin/Fondos/List/" + $(this).find(":selected").attr("value"), function (data) {
            var items = "<option>Elija Una Opcion</option>";
            $.each(data, function (i, fondos) {
                items += "<option value='" + fondos.Value + "'>" + fondos.Text + "</option>";
            });

            var num = $(this).attr("id").match(/\d+\);
            $("#Fondos" + num).html(items);
        });
    });
});
```

The for loop has been moved **inside** the ajax call, so now you'll only call the controller a single time, create the options and bind them to the 5 select elements.

I added a class to the select elements so that you could use that as your change event selector and I changed the selector to get the value of the current select element's selected option. Finally, I grab the number out of the select element's id and use that to get the proper "#Fondos" element.

It may need a little tweaking, but it should get you started...

**EDIT**
To answer the question of what this line does:

```
var num = $(this).attr("id").match(/\d+\);
```

Since the change selector applies to **all** the admin selects, we need to find the matching Fondos element. That *should* get the number from the id of the Admin select list and then you can use that to get the proper Fondos element on the next line:

```
$("#Fondos" + num).html(items);
```

Hope that helps clear things up :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It solved my problem to poblate the Administradoras select, but "Fondos" is not working, i think this is the line:
 var num = $(this).attr("id").match(/\d+\);
But i don't understand so well what is doing there.